# asp.net core strange session behavior

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, session

There is a strange issue, the session has lost a value.
Here is the steps to reproduce this issue:

1. open vs2019, and choose "ASP.NET Core Web App(Model-View-Controller)" template.
2. Leave the project name as default: WebApplication1.
3. choose Target Framework: .NET 5.0, "None" Authentication Type.
4. Use this code for Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSession(options => { options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this code for Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((context, ILoggingBuilder) =>
                {
                    ILoggingBuilder.AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning);
                    ILoggingBuilder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
                    ILoggingBuilder.AddDebug();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

this following code for Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

    <button onclick="SubmitImage(0)">SubmitImage</button>
    <button onclick="GetNextImage(0)">GetNextImage 0</button>
    <button onclick="GetNextImage(1)">GetNextImage 1</button>
    <button onclick="GetImage()">GetNextImage 0 + 1</button>
    <button onclick="GetImage2()">GetNextImage2 0 + 1</button>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetNextImage(i) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetNextImage/" + i,
                type: "get",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(i);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                }
            });
        }

        function SubmitImage(i) {
            $.post("/Home/Compare/" + i, function (e) {
                alert("success");
            }).fail(function (xhr, status, info) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            });
        }

        function GetImage() {
            GetNextImage(0); GetNextImage(1);
        }

        function GetImage2() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetNextImage/" + 0,
                type: "get",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("0");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/GetNextImage/" + 1,
                        type: "get",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("1");
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
}
```

At last, the following code is for HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }


        public IActionResult GetNextImage(int id)
        {
            string objName = "";
            if (id == 0)
            {
                objName = "ImageTagModelTop";  // top image
            }
            else
            {
                objName = "ImageTagModelBottom";  // bottom image
            }

            string model = HttpContext.Session.GetString(objName);
            if (model != null)
            {
            }

            string modelnew = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            HttpContext.Session.SetString(objName, modelnew);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Session: {HttpContext.Session.Id}   {objName}:{modelnew}");

            return Ok();
        }


        public IActionResult Compare(int id)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Session: {HttpContext.Session.Id}");
            string top = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ImageTagModelTop");
            string bottom = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ImageTagModelBottom");

            if (top == null)
                return StatusCode(406, "top");
            if (bottom == null)
                return StatusCode(406, "bottom");

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Please remember to install Newtonsoft.Json Package.

Before run this example, please make sure: Jquery version is jQuery JavaScript Library v3.5.1
Now, lets run it:
The following operations will lead to different scenarios:

Scenario A: first of all, restart debug

1. click button: GetNextImage 0
2. click button: GetNextImage 1
3. click button: SubmitImage
   And then you can get "success" alert.

Scenario B: first of all, restart debug

1. click button: GetNextImage 0 + 1
2. click button: SubmitImage
   And then you can get "top" alert or "bottom" alert, that differs.

Scenario C: first of all, restart debug

1. click button: GetNextImage2 0 + 1
2. click button: SubmitImage
   And then you can get "success".

So can anyone told me why scenario B failed?
Thank you very much, this stuck me several days.
EDIT:2023/3/9 I test more on scenario B, I found they have the same request data. I copied them from browser run in F12 mode.

```
:authority: localhost:44309
:method: GET
:path: /Home/GetNextImage/0
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.o83foM2chuM=CfDJ8Gw-GSx5k5pPsftWf04glopQhp-i3KKqOKzLzD7eaIV5ibPACwXQwjXrzhOhWt4qNtw4wskW6thpjiH4Hozvgmtgcy5YzVxy5MDZcLkWEPdua0Ynhuc3xdQ7YeN1a1zFaK15RgKJyULgoWKWPeC1SFw; .AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8Gw-GSx5k5pPsftWf04glop4NxL9N9R7OJWj2UMYlHyPbRhlgmucKlghUexJdNGQ48RBSSrVZUDwXRkBkUMkZ5zG0OgNoR4gjXeMyGpTzfyV9O2j1kDdkaxUizHwmoI_oStb28BQER95butXRTpvp5cfZn9gETdmyBl0nrNk79P7xf0UVhvZ37E5uQXWYWKRqFuwvEgV-dYDUQR0OYBhuUC8bNppXqJKScrXOsUP30Q8UTrOUxRBWZHR4Whuy9Rdqn41P9jBy9w3wYu-O3wZPmrc6dwextX3s9L960wyWaSI0veMATB-7ViHrmjkTVk4BJOXM7b3_qntFagB-w0vZSMGM4ODKJDsITBjsILBc8o7j-t9lhVid126dJJTOsu2X4Fje9dUAXizp_W2dLnnqZnWhlt2ClnA5SoBr6YqvENTNziF-t-aDDpf49HVyjC3jw; .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8Gw%2BGSx5k5pPsftWf04gloqOCxRn7WSvae%2FEeJMVA76P9wvwxd8XbXabx4B9%2FzRAvxcC%2F%2BgGGWwoPAFQrVbPeZk7KWiuzs1IjbgyyVNzMau%2BJ9sWHvcvK2UANq8lOldVqsHQ803oVCJImrhy8M33eRDpEIIWnpUbdX7Y57GXfmhx
referer: https://localhost:44309/Home/CompareTag
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.63
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

and this is for the second one:

```
:authority: localhost:44309
:method: GET
:path: /Home/GetNextImage/1
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.o83foM2chuM=CfDJ8Gw-GSx5k5pPsftWf04glopQhp-i3KKqOKzLzD7eaIV5ibPACwXQwjXrzhOhWt4qNtw4wskW6thpjiH4Hozvgmtgcy5YzVxy5MDZcLkWEPdua0Ynhuc3xdQ7YeN1a1zFaK15RgKJyULgoWKWPeC1SFw; .AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8Gw-GSx5k5pPsftWf04glop4NxL9N9R7OJWj2UMYlHyPbRhlgmucKlghUexJdNGQ48RBSSrVZUDwXRkBkUMkZ5zG0OgNoR4gjXeMyGpTzfyV9O2j1kDdkaxUizHwmoI_oStb28BQER95butXRTpvp5cfZn9gETdmyBl0nrNk79P7xf0UVhvZ37E5uQXWYWKRqFuwvEgV-dYDUQR0OYBhuUC8bNppXqJKScrXOsUP30Q8UTrOUxRBWZHR4Whuy9Rdqn41P9jBy9w3wYu-O3wZPmrc6dwextX3s9L960wyWaSI0veMATB-7ViHrmjkTVk4BJOXM7b3_qntFagB-w0vZSMGM4ODKJDsITBjsILBc8o7j-t9lhVid126dJJTOsu2X4Fje9dUAXizp_W2dLnnqZnWhlt2ClnA5SoBr6YqvENTNziF-t-aDDpf49HVyjC3jw; .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8Gw%2BGSx5k5pPsftWf04gloqOCxRn7WSvae%2FEeJMVA76P9wvwxd8XbXabx4B9%2FzRAvxcC%2F%2BgGGWwoPAFQrVbPeZk7KWiuzs1IjbgyyVNzMau%2BJ9sWHvcvK2UANq8lOldVqsHQ803oVCJImrhy8M33eRDpEIIWnpUbdX7Y57GXfmhx
referer: https://localhost:44309/Home/CompareTag
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.63
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Thank you.

Comment: the second request started before the first request has done,and since you were trying with the same browser/computer,it shares the same session

Comment: Hi RuiKai Feng, I do want to both the request share the same session, but they didn't.  So I want to know why.

Comment: I tested again today,i think i got what happened,I tested like Click GetNextImage 0 =>click GetNextImage 1 =>click GetNextImage 0 + 1 yesterday,and missed the true reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with scenario B is that you can have 2 parallel ajax calls (a in ajax means asynchronous).
You use `SessionExtensions` which means that your string value depends on the session.
It can happen that you (first or second) value is stored in another session. Here you have 2 calls directly one after the other.

You can see this when you display the `sessionid` (in SetObject, GetObject) -> `Debug.WriteLine($"Session: {session.Id}");`

Comment: Hi @PinBack, thanks. I indeed got different session id the scenario B, But why does different session occur in scenario B, and the same session on another two scenarios?, all requests in above cases are asynchronous.

Comment: I think that's a timing problem. If you call the second `GetNextImage` delayed, it works: `setTimeout(function () { GetNextImage(1);}, 500);`

Comment: One more note: if your call of `IActionResult GetNextImage(int id)` takes longer than 500 ms you have again two sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I tested mutipule times,they all performed as below:

If I test as below:

click `GetNextImage 0 + 1` => click `GetNextImage 0 + 1`

After the first click,it output two different sessionId,
After the second click,it output two same sessionId
[image]

If I test as below:

Click  `GetNextImage 0` =>click  `GetNextImage 1` =>click `GetNextImage 0 + 1`

it will always output the same sessionid

[image]

I think it just because you tried with ajax call,the second call started before the first call was done(the two request both don't have the session cookie),and when .net handle the first two request,it created two different session for the two request,and the two session cookie share the same name,so one of them would be corrupted, but if you tried the second time ( seesion cookie already exist) .net would know they share the same session.

as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state-1):

> Empty sessions aren't retained. The session must have at least one
> value set to persist the session across requests. When a session isn't
> retained, a new session ID is generated for each new request.

Comment: Thank you for the test. I agree with you on the reference. If the session is empty, it will generate a new session ID. But refer to my EDIT, the ajax request has already token the session ID, and both the two requests took the exactly same cookie, but the server treat them in different ways. You can also add LOG in the Index Action, and you can find the session already is generated when request the Index page.